# pythonでelseを含むとエラーが出ます。対処法が全くわかりません。

Tags: python

この様なプログラムなのですが、elseがどうもおかしい様です。ターミナルで実行してみると、SyntaxError: invalid syntaxと出てきます。何方か解決策をご教授願います。

```
a = input("数字を入力してください。a=")
a = int(a)

if a%4 == 0 and a%100 != 0:
    print("これは閏年です。")

    if a%400 == 0:
        print("閏年です。おめでとう。")

        else:
            print("閏年ではありません")
```

Answer (score 1):

`if-else` のインデントが揃っていないのが原因に見えます。

**修正後:**

```
    if a%400 == 0:
        print("閏年です。おめでとう。")

    else:
        print("閏年ではありません")
```

Answer (score 1):

質問されているエラーの解決策としてcubickさんの回答は正しいです。ただ、おそらくコーディングしたいのはうるう年を判定するロジックと推測します。それならインデントを揃えて構文としてエラーが無くなってもロジックとしては誤っています。もし課題なら答えになってしまいますが、下記は正しいロジックと構文の例です。

```
if a % 400 == 0 or (a % 4 == 0 and a % 100 != 0):
    print("閏年です。")
else:
    print("閏年ではありません")
```